# Django does not use index on ordering

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing, django-orm

I'm trying to optimize a query in Django (version 1.11) that I use in a prefetch. So I have a StaffProfile model that has a relation to Wages like this:

```py
class Wages(Model):
  # ...
  staff = models.ForeignKey('StaffProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=50)


class StaffProfile(Model):
  # ...
  objects = StaffProfileManager.from_queryset(StaffQuerySet)()
```

The `StaffQuerySet` has a dedicated method:

```py
class StaffQuerySet(QuerySet):
  def my_prefetch(
  ) -> QuerySet:
    return self.prefetch_related(
      Prefetch(
        'wages_set',
        queryset=Wages.objects.filter(
          # ...
        ).order_by(
          Upper('title')
        ),
        to_attr='prefetched_wages'
      ),
    )
```

What I noticed is that When I run this query: `Wages.objects.all().order_by(Upper('title'))` my database (PostgreSQL) obviously sorts the results (below is the output from the EXPLAIN run on the generated SQL):

```
Sort  (cost=21.31..21.86 rows=220 width=166)
  Sort Key: (upper((title)::text))
  ->  Seq Scan on staff_wages  (cost=0.00..12.75 rows=220 width=166)
```

The generated query is:

```
In [25]: str(Wages.objects.all().order_by(Upper('title')).only('title').query)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[25]: 'SELECT "staff_wages"."uuid", "staff_wages"."title" FROM "staff_wages" ORDER BY UPPER("staff_wages"."title") ASC'
```

So I've tried to set an index on the `title` field. In order to achieve this I've created a migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  dependencies = [
    ('staff', '0020_merge_20201116_0929'),
  ]

  operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
      sql='CREATE INDEX "staff_wages_title_upper_idx" ON "staff_wages" (UPPER("title"));',
      reverse_sql='DROP INDEX "staff_wages_title_upper_idx";'
    )
  ]
```

I've run it and I see it was created in the database. However, when I now run my query, the `EXPLAIN` gives exactly the same output, whereas I expected it to use my index. What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different index than a b-tree? Or is it impossible to achieve what I want?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause generated by `.filter(...)` needs to be considered too.

Comment: What exactly is the generated SQL statement, and how is the table defined.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've updated my question with the generated query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you create an index to support the sort, PostgreSQL may choose not to use it if it thinks that a sort is cheaper.

To decide the question if PostgreSQL does not choose the index because it cannot or because it thinks that a sort would be better, you can temporarily discourage sorting:

```
SET enable_sort = off;
```

This does not completely disable sorting, but puts an astronomical cost penalty on it, so that the optimizer will choose a different plan if possible.

Then `EXPLAIN` the query again. If your index is still not used, it cannot be used. If the index is used, compare the estimated cost to the cost of the plan with the sort. It should be lower.

You can use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` to actually execute the query and display the execution time along with the estimates. That way you can check if the optimizer made the right choice. If not, and the index scan is faster, it could be that the parameters `random_page_cost` or `effective_cache_size` are not set to describe your system correctly.

Comment: Well, I've played around with this for a moment and I've found out that it never uses the index. After adding a WHERE clause (as pointed out in the comments under the question) it turns out that I get the best performance when indexing only the columns used in the WHERE clause and that indexing UPPER(title) results in poorer performance. Thank you for the help, it was very informative :-)